# CRUD using Grails 3.1.x Spring Security with Rest

Tags: rest, spring-security, grails-3.1

Trying to develop a web CRUD application using Grails 3.1.X Spring Security with REST.
Any tutorials with examples would help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Security Core plugin (http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html) is a good place to start.